# How to connect Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to Java Program

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a task, which involves adding a database to a Java GUI program, has anyone connected Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to a Java program? Please do assist with the syntax I could attempt, also provide steps with regards to drivers I might need to install.

Comment: You mean the you want to access a SQL Server database from a Java program? You wouldn't need to connect the program to management studio, just the database.

Comment: You probably want to use JDBC. Microsoft provide a [JDBC driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server).

Comment: You don't connect to SSMS - you connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Check the Microsoft documentation: [Getting started with the JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/getting-started-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)